# Issue with a Poisson process and its jump times

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Poisson process and $$T_n = \inf\{t\geq 0, \ N_t \geq n\}$$ Now given $t \ge 0$ how to compute
$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N_t} X_{T_n}\right] $$
? where $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a stochastic process independant of $(N_t)$. I know that $$P(N_t=k)=e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}, \quad T_n \sim \Gamma\left(n,\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)$$
but have no idea of thee joint distribution of $(T_1,\cdots, T_k) | \{ N_t = k\}$

Comment: What do you know about $X_t$ ?

Comment: Try working recursively.  Can you say what is the distribution of $(T_1,T_2)|{N_t = 2}$?

Comment: @Bertrand R : càdlàg

Comment: @josh : $T_1$ and $T_2-T_1$ are iid exponentials so we get the joint law of $(X,X+Y)$ with $X\sim Y\sim \mathcal{E}(\lambda)$. Then repeat the process ok I get it thanks.

Comment: Actually I may not need the joint distribution because of my linear expression. However I still have to compute $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{(\lambda t)^k(\lambda u)^n}{k! n!}$$ Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the density of $T_n$, you know that, for every $n\geqslant1$,
$$
E[X_{T_n}:T_n\lt t]=\int_0^tE[X_s]\mathrm e^{-\lambda s}\lambda^{n}\frac{s^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\mathrm ds.
$$
Since $[T_n\lt t]=[N_t\geqslant n]$, summing these on $n\geqslant1$ yields
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}X_{T_n}\mathbf 1_{T_n\lt t}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}X_{T_n}\mathbf 1_{N_t\geqslant n}=\sum_{n=1}^{N_t}X_{T_n},
$$
hence
$$
E\left[\sum_{n=1}^{N_t}X_{T_n}\right]=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\int_0^tE[X_s]\mathrm e^{-\lambda s}\lambda^{n}\frac{s^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\mathrm ds=\lambda\int_0^tE[X_s]\mathrm ds.
$$
Which corresponds to the presentation of the Poisson process $(N_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ as a jump process with constant intensity $\lambda$.

Comment: Very nice ! Could not separate $T_n$ from $N_t$ which is the reason I got stuck. Thanks @Did.